# Unable to load data from PHP to listview

Tags: java, php, android

I am following [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) tutorial. I have trouble with that. The problem is when I run the source code with the internet URL (which connects through internet), the application is working perfectly. But when I am using the local URL, it show loading but won’t load the data. I used the following URL

```
private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1234/androidhive.php";
```

The actual URL was

```
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";
```

finally I get this from my logcat

```
12-12 15:40:48.311: D/Response:(1552): > null
12-12 15:40:48.311: E/ServiceHandler(1552): Couldn't get any data from the url
```

The PHP file used

```
<?php
echo '{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
  ]
}';
?>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import info.androidhive.jsonparsing.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    //private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1234/androidhive.php";

    private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE = "phone";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_HOME = "home";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_OFFICE = "office";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        SingleContactActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_EMAIL, cost);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        // Calling async task to get json
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String address = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);

                        // Phone node is JSON Object
                        JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject(TAG_PHONE);
                        String mobile = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);
                        String home = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_HOME);
                        String office = phone.getString(TAG_PHONE_OFFICE);

                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        contact.put(TAG_EMAIL, email);
                        contact.put(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE, mobile);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_EMAIL,
                            TAG_PHONE_MOBILE }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                            R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

ServiceHandler.java

```
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class ServiceHandler {

    static String response = null;
    public final static int GET = 1;
    public final static int POST = 2;

    public ServiceHandler() {

    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
        return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
    }

    /*
     * Making service call
     * @url - url to make request
     * @method - http request method
     * @params - http request params
     * */
    public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type
            if (method == POST) {
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // adding post params
                if (params != null) {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                }

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            } else if (method == GET) {
                // appending params to url
                if (params != null) {
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                            .format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            }
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
}
```

SingleContact.java

```
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import info.androidhive.jsonparsing.R;

public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {

    // JSON node keys
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
        String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
        String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);

        // Displaying all values on the screen
        TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
        TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
        TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

        lblName.setText(name);
        lblEmail.setText(email);
        lblMobile.setText(mobile);
    }
}
```

Actvitymain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Main ListView 
         Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
    -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_sigle_contact.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="10dp">
  <!-- Name Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/name_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:textColor="#43bd00"/>
  <!-- Email Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/email_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#acacac"/>
  <!-- Mobile Label -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/mobile_label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListItem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Email label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#acacac" />

    <!-- Mobile number label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Mobile: "
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The project is avaiable with the [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)
Please help me with this, I don’t why it not loading the data from the PHP file. 
have anyone have idea about this?

Comment: You sure there isn't a problem with your PHP pushing down the data? from your error results it seems its saying it got no data at all.  Have you verified your at least getting a response back period?

Comment: i checked by my browser it's showing the data

Comment: Try to put this in the first line: header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: the URL i used won't give anything. but i have used same type of URL in different application for login, its working

Comment: for your information when i shutdown the WAMP server only, the application can retrieve data from the original URL

Comment: Open a browser in your adroid emulator and check the url there.

Comment: i will check and let u know

Comment: the page get irresponsive @HarryFink